# call_user_func_array non static method call

Tags: php, routes

I have this class for test propose that is loaded using `FastRoute` on the same page where the library is loaded:

```
class Controller {
 public function demo()
 {
   echo 'Hello world';
 }
}
```

Every time I access the root of my project which is a mapped route, I get this strange error

`Deprecated: Non-static method Controller::demo() should not be called statically`

I can't understand why the `call:user_func_array()` is thinking that the method is static.

here is the test code for routing. Any suggestion is appreciated

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use FastRoute\RouteCollector;
use FastRoute\simpleDispatcher;
use FastRoute\Dispatcher;

$dispatcher = FastRoute\simpleDispatcher(function(FastRoute\RouteCollector $r){
    // test route
    $r->addRoute('GET', '/', 'Controller@demo');
});

// Fetch method and URI from somewhere
$httpMethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Strip query string (?foo=bar) and decode URI
if (false !== $pos = strpos($uri, '?')) {
    $uri = substr($uri, 0, $pos);
}
$uri = rawurldecode($uri);

$routeInfo = $dispatcher->dispatch($httpMethod, $uri);
switch ($routeInfo[0]) {
    case FastRoute\Dispatcher::NOT_FOUND:
        // ... 404 Not Found
        break;
    case FastRoute\Dispatcher::METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED:
        $allowedMethods = $routeInfo[1];
        // ... 405 Method Not Allowed
        break;
    case FastRoute\Dispatcher::FOUND:
        $handler = $routeInfo[1];
        $vars = $routeInfo[2];
        list($class, $method) = explode("@", $handler, 2);
        call_user_func_array([$class, $method], $vars);
        break;
}

?>
```

Comment: ```call_user_func_array([new $class(), $method], $vars);```

Comment: *"I can't understand why the call:user_func_array() is thinking that the method is static." -- it doesn't. On the contrary, it says that the method is not static and you try to call it in a static manner. I.e. without using an instance but the class name.

Comment: @axiac it was a mistake I've made, I forgot to put the new keyword before the $class variable. This because I was using PHP-DI for dependency injection, but not in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is because you're not specifying a class instance (object) but the class itself.
Try to instantiate a new object with `new $class()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It was a fault of mine.